# How do I use AzureStoragePersistence and Outbox at the same time?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus6

So I was moving my NSB setup off of SQL server and onto azure service bus and figured I might as well use azure storage for persistence as well. I'm unclear on how to set this up because I'm also using outbox and I can't use azure storage with it. I'm using the web.config for connections strings, and it sort of only lets me set NServiceBus/Persistence once, so ... I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to various reasons the outbox is only supported on SQL-Server and RavenDb. Read more about it here : https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/

At the bottom of the document there's a note that only those two persisters support the outbox feature.

Answer (score 0):

Add to what Dennis said - you cannot use Storage Persistence with the Outbox feature. Outbox feature requires business data and outgoing transaction to participate in the same transaction. This is only possible with Azure SQL server. With Azure Storage persistence this is not an option. Storage supports table batched operations, but not transactions.